# How to import csv file with code to a tabular model

Tags: c#, ssas-tabular, import-csv

I'm setting up a web service where a user uploads csv file which then is added to the SASS tabular model. Is this even possible through code? If so how could it be done? I know that you can do it manually through VS, but i need it automatic.

It's possible to make a work-around where the csv file is uploaded the to a sql database and from there on loaded on a tabular mode. But since the file sizes are quite big(~500Mb) it might some time perform this.

My current code, connect to SASS server and copy data from sql database to SASS

```
 public void Add()
        {
            string connStr = @"Data Source=localhost:64731";
            string dataSource = "AdventureWorksDW2017";
            string measureExpression = @"SUM('DimEployee'[Freq])";

            using (Server serv = new Server())
            {
                serv.Connect(connStr);

                string dbName = serv.Databases.GetNewName("TestBase3000");

                Database db = new Database()
                {
                    Name = dbName,
                    ID = dbName,
                    CompatibilityLevel = 1200,
                    StorageEngineUsed = StorageEngineUsed.TabularMetadata
                };

                db.Model = new Model()
                {
                    Name = "Tabular model test",
                    Description = "Test"
                };

                //define data source
                db.Model.DataSources.Add(new ProviderDataSource()
                {
                    Name = dataSource,
                    Description = "Aventure works",
                    //for SQL server
                    ConnectionString =
                        @"Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=DESKTOP-K9RTS02\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksDW2017;Integrated Security=SSPI",
                    ImpersonationMode = Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ImpersonationMode.ImpersonateServiceAccount,
                });

                // add tables
                // dimension table
                db.Model.Tables.Add(new Table()
                {
                    Name = db.Model.Tables.GetNewName("DimProductSubcategory"),
                    Description = "Testing",
                    Partitions =
                    {
                        new Partition()
                        {
                            Name = "Partition 1",
                            Source = new QueryPartitionSource()
                            {
                                DataSource = db.Model.DataSources[dataSource],
                                Query = @"SELECT ProductSubcategoryKey, ProductSubcategoryAlternateKey, EnglishProductSubcategoryName FROM DimProductSubcategory",
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Columns =
                    {
                        new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DataColumn()
                        {
                            Name = "Id",
                            DataType = DataType.Int64,
                            SourceColumn = "ProductSubcategoryKey",
                        },
                        new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DataColumn()
                        {
                            Name = "AltId",
                            DataType = DataType.Int64,
                            SourceColumn = "ProductSubcategoryAlternateKey",
                        },
                        new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DataColumn()
                        {
                            Name = "EnglishSubCategory",
                            DataType = DataType.String,
                            SourceColumn = "EnglishProductSubcategoryName",
                        }
                    }
                });
                serv.Databases.Add(db);

                //deploy database to SSAS Server
                db.Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull);

                //process new model so it's available to query
                db.Model.RequestRefresh(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType.Full);
                db.Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull);
         }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working for you in this code?

Comment: This code is specifically for uploading data from an sql database. I would like to upload from an csv file

Comment: Check out this library to import CSVs to data model: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: @Matt Not sure how this library could help me. Could you explain a little bit more? The only thing this library does is helps to parse the csv file, but has nothing to do with inserting it into SASS